# Not able to pass the command line arguments using docker run to a Shell Script file

Tags: shell, docker, parameters, server, runtime-error

Command Used:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 80:9000 c822030cc576 sh /app/test/play/docker-entrypoint.sh /app/test/play/servers/server01/play/conf/override.conf /app/log/nflott/play true dev
```

My Parameters:

```
$2:/app/test/play/servers/server01/play/conf/override.conf
$3:/app/log/nflott/play
$4:true
$5:dev Which needs to be passed to the docker-entrypoint.sh Script
```

My entrypoint.sh Script Code:

```
        echo "CONFIG:$2
        echo "LOG_HOME:$3"
        echo "SKIP_LOGFILE:$4"
        echo "LOG_ENV:$5

        /app/test/play/servers/server01/play/bin/apiserver  \
         -Dconfig.file=/app/test/play/servers/server01/play/conf/override.conf \
         -Dpidfile.path=/app/test/play/servers/server01/RUNNING_PID \
         -DLOG_HOME=$3 \
         -DSKIP_LOGFILE=$4 \
         -DLOG_ENV=$5 \

     Error:
        CONFIG:/app/test/play/servers/server01/play/conf/override.conf
        LOG_HOME:/app/log/nflott/play
        SKIP_LOGFILE:true
        LOG_ENV:dev
        Bad root server path: /app/nflott/play/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Seems after the echo statement my parameters are not getting passed to the logic block and its failing with Bad Root server Path issue. How to resolve the Bad root serer path error and run my script?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO they might be getting passed as args of the docker command. You can instead try -e docker option to pass them as some named env variables to the docker container and then access inside your script.

Answer (score 0):

You may use special `--entrypoint` flag and pass params in `cmd`:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 80:9000 --entrypoint /app/test/play/docker-entrypoint.sh c822030cc576 /app/test/play/servers/server01/play/conf/override.conf /app/log/nflott/play true dev
```